# Fully clear terminal on Mac OS X without exiting Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

I'm running a simple utility with Python3 that takes text input delimited by comma, tab, or pipe  (usually copied from csv) and joins the text around " | " for readability.

After an empty input is submitted, the terminal should clear ready for the next input.

This works perfectly on Fedora 31, but on OS X the terminal is just moved down to hide the rest of the text, instead of actually clearing it. I have tried using "clear", "tput reset" and not sure why this isn't working. If I use system("tput reset") in Perl instead of Python, it properly clears the terminal on OS X.

```
from os import system
import re

def clearScreen():
    system('tput reset')


clearScreen()

while True:
    block = []
    line = '_'

    while line:
        line = input('')
        if len(line) > 0:
            block.append(line)
        else:
            clearScreen()

    for row in block:
        print(' | '.join(re.split('[|,\t]', row)) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a quirk of Mac.

Use `system("printf '\\33c\\e[3J'")` instead and it will work.